# Is there a word describing woman's action who behaves cute, and tries to charm a man?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

When a woman is in front of a man who she is fond of, some woman does the unusual action to look cute. Obviously, she wants to charm him, to give a good impression, or to show her affection.  Her voice sounds like attractive humming, and she does special action like supporting her cheek with hands, shaking her heads like cute doggy, and beating a man's chest softly, and so on. Is there a word or a phrase describing this action of the woman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**coquettish**

> (of a woman) characteristically flirtatious, especially in a teasing, lighthearted manner.

([source](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/coquettish))

There is also a noun form, *coquette*, for the woman herself, and an adverb *coquettishly* to describe her actions.